# Google analytics traffice source is untraceable IP?

Tags: ip, google, web

Can someone explain how this is possible.

I am getting traffic to my website coming from this IP: 10.201.3.31:15871

I can't find where or what that is. It seems to be an unallocated address block. Is this a bug in Google analytics? Or something odder?

Comment: What hapens when you try to traceroute back to this address?

Comment: I get lots of *'s, which I think means it doesn't find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK (and I could be wrong), Google Analytics is a client-side JavaScript. Google collect stats passively - the client loads your site, executes the JS and their browser sends data directly to Google Analytics. GA doesn't connect to your website to collect these statistics so the likelihood of 10.201.3.31 being a Google address is pretty remote.

10.0.0.0/8 is an RFC1918 block which means that it is reserved for use on private networks. Is it possible that 10.201.3.31 is one of the addresses on your LAN?

Another possibility is that someone (or some thing) is trying to access your website from behind a router that isn't NATing the LAN address (10.201.3.31) to a routable public IP address.

Comment: It could also be a proxy server that exposes inernal LAN ip address.

Comment: I don't think its our lan, but how would I check for certain?

Comment: Open a command prompt (or terminal in Linux) and run ipconfig (Windows) or ifconfig (Linux). That'll give you your IP address, which may or may not be similar to the 10.201.3.31 one. Of course, the web server may be on a different network to the one that you are on so that mightn't reveal much - in which case, ifconfig on the server will tell you whether or not it has any privately addressed NICs and what the IP might be for them.

Comment: look into the apache logs on your server, you should see that ipaddress, and do a traceroute from there...its not possible that a LAN outside from your LAN can connect directly without any tunnel, could be a VPN...also...

Comment: Ok. Its not our webserver's IP or our office IP, internal or external.

Comment: Traceroute on that IP from the webserver doesn't find it. It does 30 hops (max) and returns mainly a list of *'s.